# How can I recover deleted files from Windows Mobile 6.5 internal memory storage on phone Samsung gt-b7300 (no sd card)

Tags: data-recovery, windows-phone

I have a Samsung gt-b7300 phone. It does not have sd card. It can't be for some reason tethered as usb mass storage. It has Windows Mobile 6.5 OS.

I would like to restore deleted files from it.

I thought of cloning it byte after byt creating image and feeding it into testdisk or photoreq. But can't find a way to do it.

How can I recover deleted files?

Answer (score 0):

A good OS to recover deleted photos is [Kali Linux due to its forensics tools installed.](https://tools.kali.org/forensics) We will be using foremost to do this. For this example, we will use my USB. If you do not want to use kali linux

1. Before we start. Open terminal and type in `fdisk -l` to list drives connected. [image: USB listed]

   /dev/sdb1` is the USB connected.

   2. Run in terminal `foremost -i /dev/sdb1` 
      [image: foremost]

This process can take a long time. When foremost is done it will create a `output` folder with all the recovered data.

Comment: That's great, thanks. It will be useful once I can make that phone show up as mass storage device, disk or usb stick. Until then I most probably cannot use Your answer